# How can I Inject dependency using bean method name?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

For example, now I have a dependency class:

```
public classA {
  @Bean(name = "s1")
  public Class1 s1 {}

  @Bean(name = "s2")
  public Class2 s2 (@Name("s1")) {}
}
```

So in classA there two methods s1 and s2, and have bean method name as s1 and s2, respectively.

Now is it possible for me to inject Class2 using bean method name s2?
to do sth like:

```
@Inject @Name private Class2 obj;
```

Comment: Assuming your both classes are from e.g. implementing the same interface, then yes you want to autowire by name and explicitly declare the name as the bean name or use `@Qualifier` or `@Named` equivalent.

Comment: thanks. No, these two class are totally different, not implementing the same interface. So can I still use @qualifier?

Comment: Then you dont need anything at all, name it how you like when injecting.

Comment: So I keep using my old line above: "@Inject @Name private Class2 obj"?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@Qualifier` for that.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

   @Bean
   @Qualifier("s1")
   public Class1 s1 {}

   @Bean
   @Qualifier("s2")
   public Class2 s2 () {
       Class1 s1 = s1(); 
       // ...
   }

}
```

And in your application code autowire based on qualifier.

```
@Component
public class Client {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("s2")
    private Class2 c2;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: **This annotation may be used on a field or parameter as a qualifier for candidate beans when autowiring.** Remove `@Qualifier` from your `@Bean` annotated methods, as this is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I need to point out, these two classes have no relations, not implementing same interface. So is your solution still working?

Comment: Yes, it is not dependent on that.

Comment: Thanks, but I read online, and indeed those tutorials said "@Qualifier" is for distinguishing those beans from the same type. Maybe this is not the only usage of Qualifier?

Comment: Actually I just tried your code, it's not working on my side. It returns null.

Comment: Qualifiers overrides the default bean mapping. If you get null (and not a no such bean exception) there is an issue with how you’ve configured spring.

Comment: Thx. So that means Inject is working(here it's @Autowired), but it's configuration problem? Also can you elaborate more on what configuration you mean here?

Comment: Yes, please see the pastebin link in comments. That is a spring boot config that works

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
    public class Config {


   @Bean
   public Class1 s1 {
   return Class1;
   }

   @Bean
   public Class2 s2 () {    
   return Class2;
      // ...
   }

    enter code here

}
```

The below application class has the bean autowired with the method name as qualifier

```
  @Component
    public class Client {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("s2")
        private Class2 c2;

        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Above code is the configuration class which creates the bean which can be autowired using the method name as qualifier